# Aligning text vertically relative to other subfigures with subcaption

Tags: vertical-alignment, subcaption

I want to add vertical (rotated) text at the beginning of a row of subfigures using the subcaption package.  My solution right now is to create a separate subfigure:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \begin{subfigure}{1in}
    \rotatebox{90}{\makebox[2in]{center}}
    \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}{1in}
    \rule{1in}{2in}
    \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}{1in}
    \rule{1in}{2in}
    \captionsetup{skip=0pt}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which works fine except that I don't want any caption for the vertical text.  However if I remove the "\caption{}" line then the text is no longer vertically aligned with the two subfigures.  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There might be a simpler alternative, but you could use the starred version for the first caption:  `\caption*{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `origin=c` option to `\rotatebox` will give text that is vertically centered without the use of an extra `subfigure`.  Alternatively you can `[t]` align the subfigures are rotate with `origin=l`:

`origin=c`:

[image: Sample output]

`origin=l` and `subfigure`s with `[t]`:

[image: Second sample]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makebox[2in]{center}}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}{1in}
    \rule{1in}{2in}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}{1in}
    \rule{1in}{2in}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \rotatebox[origin=l]{90}{\makebox[2in]{center}}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{1in}
    \rule{1in}{2in}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \quad
  \begin{subfigure}[t]{1in}
    \rule{1in}{2in}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```